# In R, what is the difference between combining columns using & vs. square brackets [][]?

Tags: r

In R, what is the difference between :

```
summary(airquality$Solar.R[(airquality$Ozone>31)&(airquality$Temp>90)])
```

vs.

```
summary( (airquality[airquality$Ozone>31,][airquality$Temp>90,])$Solar.R)
```

I got slightly different results, 212.0 vs. 212.8
which is more accurate and perform better.

Comment: You probably would have found Jonathan's answer on your own if you'd tested the output of each internal calculation for each construct. Always a good idea to break a problem down into small steps to see what's going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first command is correct; the second command is incorrect. Your second command first selects the rows of `airquality` that have `Ozone > 31`, then it selects rows corresponding to the rows of `airquality` that have `Temp > 90`. The problem is that your data has already been subsetted once, so the rows don't line up the second time. If you do it this way the numerical summaries agree with your first version:

```
summary((airquality[airquality$Ozone>31,][airquality[airquality$Ozone>31,]$Temp>90,])$Solar.R)
```

Though it counts more `NA`s.

Stick with the first version.

Comment: That's a good point to remember: `DF$Column > Value` is just telling R a bunch of true/false values. R doesn't even know/care that those values came from the data frame you're trying to subset.